# Disable PyCharm SQL inspection for one statement

Tags: pycharm, ide

I really like PyCharm's SQL inspections, they are really useful and give valuable insights. But they don't work well with `psycopg2` SQL composition features. I'm building a simple query to perform multiple rows insert:

```python
from psycopg2.sql import SQL, Placeholder, Literal

def build_materials_insert(model_id, materials):
    data = SQL(", ").join(
        SQL("({model_id}, {obj_name}, {material})").format(
            model_id=Literal(model_id),
            obj_name=Literal(mat["object"]),
            material=Literal(mat["material"])
        ) for mat in materials
    )

    return SQL("INSERT INTO materials(model_id, object, material)  VALUES {values}").format(values=data)
```

And after the inspection, PyCharm shows the warning `'(' expected, got '{'`. It's valid from SQL standpoint, but not useful here, as this text in curly braces is just a format placeholder.

Using Alt-Enter to show suggestion offers just "Change SQL dialect" feature.

I can disable SQL syntax inspection in general, but I don't want to do that, as in other places it's pretty useful. I tried to find an appropriate disable comment command, but didn't find the list for the built-in SQL.

Is there some way to disable SQL validation for a particular statement, as I really like to keep my code with all green inspections result?

Answer (score 0):

After the communication with PyCharm support, appeared that there is no way to do that currently.

I've submitted a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-12657) to the DataGrip bug tracker (DB related stuff is handled by DataGrip ream), so hopefully, it will be fixed one day

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that uses PostgreSQL and Neo4j.  There does not appear to be any way that I can convince PyCharm to stop telling me that my Cypher queries are syntactically invalid.

Not annoying or anything /s.